# Union of axis-aligned hyperrectangles

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $Q$ be an axis-aligned hyperrectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $Q = \{ x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: a_i < x_i \leq b_i \}$ with $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be such hyperrectangles. 
I would want to show that

(a)
$$A\setminus B = \bigcup_{k = 1}^N C_k,$$
where $C_k$ are other axis-alligned hyperrectangles. (The intuition here is quite clear, although I'm not able to formalize it yet) and

(b)
$$N \leq 2n,$$
the exact same $N$ from above. This is totally eluding me so far, I drew pictures of hyperrectangles in up to 3 dimensions, and could indeed convince myself that up to $2n$ hyperrectangles are needed. But how to formalize it?

Any input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain _informally_ in words how you convinced yourself that $2n$ terms are enough?

Comment: In one dimension, for instance, a line $B = (c, d]$ overlapping with another line $A = (a, b]$ such that $A \setminus B$ contains two shorter lines, namely $(a, c]$ and $(d, b]$, produces $N = 2 \cdot 1 = 2$

Comment: Analogously for a rectangle and a cuboid, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to first solve the problem with $A, B,$ and $C_k$ semi-infinite hyperrectangles (where $b_i = \infty, \forall i$?)